# How to view method signatures when Objc-C is bridged to Swift and vice versa?

Tags: objective-c, swift

If I've got some Obj-C code and I'm calling this from Swift code, or I've got some Swift code that I'm calling from Objective-C. Then how can I see what the method signature for these look like.

I've done this before and remember there being an Xcode generated bridging header that contains the bridged method signatures.
But I just can't find this at all now. I seem to remember it getting generated into the derived data folder, but I just can't find it anywhere at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see how an Objective-C interface is imported into Swift, select the header file and choose "Generated Interface" from the "Related Items" button:

[image]

Example: OClass.h:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface OClass : NSObject

- (void)bar:(NSString *)string;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Generated interface:

```
open class OClass : NSObject {
    open func bar(_ string: String)
}
```

To see how a Swift class is mapped to Objective-C, select a Swift file and choose "Generated Interface -> "ProjectName.h" from the "Related Items" button:

[image]

Example: "SClass.swift"

```
class SClass: NSObject {
    @objc func foo() {

    }
}
```

"MyProject-Swift.h":

```
// ...
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9MyProject6SClass")
@interface SClass : NSObject
- (void)foo;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
// ...
```

Comment: for the .swift file Xcode is not displaying a MyProject-Swift.h file - its just showing the FileName.swift (interface). This is with Xcode 10.2. Has it changed in 10.2?

Comment: @Gruntcakes: Apparently there must be at least one Objective-C file in the project, otherwise there is no “MyProject-Swift.h” menu item.

Comment: there are dozens of Obj-C files in the project.

Comment: @Gruntcakes: Strange, it works for me. I made those screenshots with Xcode 10.2

Comment: @Gruntcakes: Can you `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` in an ObjC .m-file? Selecting the text "MyProject-Swift.h" in the Xcode edit and then "Navigate->Jump To Definition"  is an alternative method to see the contents of that file.

Answer (score -2):

**Objc to swift**

Go to your Target -> BuildSettings->(search for "Objective-C Bridging")YouProjectBridging.h
Add your other .h files by #import "OtherVisible.h" in the  "YouProjectBridging.h"

**Swift to Objc**

In each .h file where you like to use swift code.
After imports add a line `@class MySwiftClass;"`

In .m file after imports add a line

```
#import <YourProjectName-Swift.h>
```

But first in swift class that you to like call should have access modifiers set to

```
@objc open class MyswiftClass
```

Same applies to its properties and function

```
 @objc public var button : UIButton!
 @objc public override func viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: Your answer is a tutorial on how to mix swift and Obj-c. That is not my question.

Comment: Sorry I thought method signature means parameters,return value  of the func should be visible in the place where you are calling.